# IONIC / AngularJS : Add elements dynamically

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic project where I want to add a dynamic amount of buttons to the page.

On the page there is just an image. And I need to inject these buttons on top of the image.

So I get data from the web where the buttons have to be. (position)

How can I inject HTML Code from a controller like:

```
<button class="hotpoint" style="position: absolute; top: 10pt; left: 10pt"></button>
```

to the page.

I need something like:

```
for(var obj in objects)
{
   $scope.addHTML("<button style="top: obj.y; left: obj.x;">...</button>");
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: post some code you tried.

Comment: Can't do that. Because I don't now how to do. I just have a function inside a controller and want to add something like "<button class"hotpoint" style="top: 10pt; left: 10pt;">Button</button>

Comment: I **guess** you're looking for ng-style. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle. Your question should look like this: *I have a controller withe the following data exposed on the scope [code of the controller]. I would like to display the points contained in that data in the page, using the following HTML [html]. But of course, the top and left values should not be hard-coded: their value should be taken from the coordinates of the points in my data. Here is what I tried: [code]. But instead of doing what I want, it produces the following error: [error].*.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your help, but I need to add a dynamic amount of elements of the buttons. So actually I need a for loop where I can setup the button and then add it to the ion-content.

Comment: So, edit your question, and make it look like I just explained. Tell precisely what you want to achieve, what your data looks like, what you tried. Don't let us guess what you want. We can't read in your mind. And we can't see the code displayed on your screen. Also, do some research. Read the angular manual/tutorial. Looping through elements is covered in every possible angular tutorial. You shouldn't ask us about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved the problem by myself.

The trick was "ng-bind-html"

In index.html I've added a div with:

```
<div ng-bind-html="hotpoints"></div>
```

And then I can inject HTML Code in the controller like this:

```
$scope.hotpoints = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a id="but" class="hotpoint animated infinite" style="top: 100pt; left: 100pt;"></a>');
```